# Stop wget from making index.html for Options +Indexes directories

Tags: wget

I am using this command to mirror a directory tree on my server:

```
wget -m -e robots=off --no-parent --reject-regex index.html --reject-regex aaa --no-verbose --timestamp https://example.com/folders/
```

"folders" directory has an `.htaccess` file containing an `Options +Indexes` directive.

However, for each directory, it creates an `index.html` file reflecting the page the server generates showing the index of that directory.

Since it is not actually a file, there is no modification timestamp header for it. I would like to prevent wget from creating the `index.html` file.  Using `--reject-regex index.html` doesn't work.

Comment: Is the file named `index.html` or does its name look similar to `index.html?C=M;O=A` ?

Comment: "Beware that it seems you can use --reject-regex only once per wget call." (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21382873/724039 )

Comment: @harrymc no index.html exists.  the downloaded files look like index.html?MD etc.  Also, it creates 3 or more of these files with varying versions of the extension for each directory (what???)

Comment: @Luuk Thanks.  I just tried it with only the one `--reject-regex index.html` and it still creates the index.html files.

Comment: BTW, does anyone know what the numbers in the brackets mean: `URL:https://example.com/directory [1795/1795] -> "example.com/directory/file.ext" [1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have run into the same problem as in the Wget post
[How do I prevent wget from creating index.html?C=M;O=A ?](https://bug-wget.gnu.narkive.com/JJbQz2mY/how-do-i-prevent-wget-from-creating-index-html-c-m-o-a)

The answers all say that these files are unavoidable and are the result
of the way that wget works - these files contain the lists of the files
that are to be retrieved from each (sub)folder.

The proposed workarounds were about removing these files after that
the download of the entire folder tree is completed, rather than about
preventing their creation in the first place.

An example of one proposed command was :

```
find /mirrór/tree -name "*C=[DMNS];O=[AD]" -exec rm -f "{}" \;
```

Comment: Ah, well... sigh.  Yes, I've been deleting them using a similar script.  Marking this as answered +1.  Thanks.